# Angular 9 this.userData is undefine error

Tags: angular, firebase

I develop Angular 9 website with firebase backend. When user enter email and password for login, I control user permision and direct user other side if have permission. My problem is first button click send undefine error but second click work.
Here is my code:

authservice.service.ts file:

```
export class AuthService {
userData: any; 
user: Observable<User>;
constructor(
  public afs: AngularFirestore,
  public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  public router: Router,
  private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,
  public ngZone: NgZone) {
     this.afAuth.onAuthStateChanged((result) => {
     if (result) {
     this.user = this.afs.collection('user').doc<User>(result.uid).valueChanges();
     this.user.subscribe((result) => {
       this.userData = result;
      });
      this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['home']));
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
      localStorage.removeItem('useremail');
      this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['sign-in']));
    }
  });}


async SignIn(email, password) {
   await this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(async (result) => {
      localStorage.setItem("useremail", result.user.email);
      if ((this.userData.permission & 2) === 2) {
         localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
         this.router.navigate(['home']);
      }else
         this.openSnackBar("You don't have access this area");
    }).catch((error) => {
       this.openSnackBar(error.message);
    });}}
```

sign-in-component.html:

```
        <form>
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="col-12 text-capitalize" color="primary">
                <mat-label>email</mat-label>
                <input matInput #userEmail required type="email">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="col-12 text-capitalize">
                <mat-label>password</mat-label>
                <input matInput #userPassword required type="password">
            </mat-form-field>
            <button class="col-12 text-uppercase" mat-stroked-button color="primary" (click)="authService.SignIn(userEmail.value, userPassword.value)">login</button>
        </form>
```

sign-in-component.ts:

```
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public authService: AuthService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Error is: this.userData is undefine

I don't know if I doing something wrong. I tried differend approach but doesn't work. Thanks for all help.

Comment: It appears the `SignIn()` function is called before the `this.userData` variable is assigned a value. It is an asynchronous variable.

Comment: @MichaelD What would you suggest to me?

Comment: Your code is hard to follow because we dont know what calls what, the problem is clearly related to an async function but since you did not provide enough, its really hard to answer. The constructor is from the login page? And where is SignIn being called from?

Comment: @ukn Sorry about that. I give you my structure. I get user email and password from sign-in-component's form. After user submit form value on button click, I pass form value, signIn() method in AuthService. The above code is in auth.service.ts.

Comment: Constructor code using for user control, if user enter route user to home page or if not send user login page.

Comment: You need to provide the code(with the file name to make easy to seperate) and not just what you think is not working. The problem here looks simple, this.userData is undefined when you try to access this.userData.permission. Without seeing the actual code, I cant help you.

Comment: @ukn I will edit my question and give more code and description.

Comment: I edit question. Give all code above. Structure like I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have access to the userdata variable call a method inside the subscription that gets it.

```
this.user.subscribe((result) => {
      this.userData = result;
       // you could put calls to other methods that need what you get from result here. 
       //At this point in time going forward userData is defined.
    });
```

Usually asynch actions can be the result of some interaction, which avoids the need to nest inside a listener's/subscriber's code block, but if you are calling signin() programatically then it's surely getting called before the userData value is set.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it doesn't work. I remove async like you said but I get error again.

Comment: Change my code like you said with little alteration. Thanks for help. But I don't remove async.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with, this.userData variable put in SignIn method and change code to this form:

```
async SignIn(email, password) {
await this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(async (result) => {
    this.user = await this.afs.collection('user').doc<User>(result.user.uid).valueChanges();
    this.user.subscribe((result) => {
      this.userData = result;
      if ((this.userData.permission & 2) === 2) {
        localStorage.setItem("useremail", result.email);
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        this.router.navigate(['home']);
      }
      else
        this.openSnackBar("You don't have access this area");
    }).unsubscribe;

  }).catch((error) => {
    this.openSnackBar(error.message);
  });}
```

When I get user's data from firebase query my user permision and if user have permission direct him home page.